# How to import a Visual Studio solution into Mono Develop?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mono, monodevelop

I have an old C# solution developed with Visual Studio on which I would like to work again. I have installed Mono Develop (version 5.10) on Ubuntu 16.04 from the Software Centre and tried to open the `.sln` file. In the *File to Open* dialogue I am making sure the *Solution Files* option is selected:

[image]

But instead of setting up the solution, Mono Develop simply opens the file in text mode:

[image]

The same happens if I try to open a `.csprj` file.

How could I exactly open or import a solution into Mono Develop?

**Update**: This issue is now reported as bug [44864](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44864).

Comment: That looks like you are opening the .sln file directly into the text editor. If you are using File - Open make sure you have Solution Workbench selected in the File to Open dialog.

Comment: Hi Matt, I do not have a "Solution Workbench" option, but I have "Solution Files". I attached a new image to the question.

Comment: Solution Workbench should be an option in the Open With drop down at the bottom of the dialog. The Solution Files is a file filter which filters everything apart from .sln files and project files (.csproj) and will have no affect on how the solution is opened

Comment: What does "should have" exactly means? Is there a bug with this version of Mono Develop?

Comment: I cannot see "should have" in my comment. By "should be" I mean "will be unless it is not working properly". There is no bug that I am aware of. For me I can see Solution Workbench in the Open With drop down in Xamarin Studio 5.10 on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). It is the default option for me.

Comment: This question is not about Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I meant MonoDevelop since Xamarin Studio is not available for Linux.

Comment: Please follow on this discussion at the [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123937/opening-vs-solutions-with-mono-develop).